# how to backup your full environment?

Tags: force.com

we have a full sandbox, and I was asked to back it up. the issue is that we're concernec about losing stuff like templates, reports, workflow and validaation rules.

I downloaded everything locally via the force.com IDE, but the preference is that we have it online. we don't need the data.

Is there a way to do this? I was thinking a change set, but is there a better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a package (unmanaged), and then upload it to the AppExchange as a private package (will not be listed). You will be able to reinstall the configuration items that were in the package at any time so long as the package itself isn't deleted.

You could also just ZIP the results of the extract and put it into a Document in salesforce.com. I'd recommend your production instance so it doesn't accidentally get wiped out by a refresh. You could also store the ZIP file as a Static Resource.

Comment: Is this a config box that can be used to just back up code and settings and pull info as needed when refreshing a sandbox, I have seen my deploy team at one of my jobs do something similar, every time there was a PRD deploy they used to pull all the setting on a config box and then push the data,can something similar be done before refreshing the sandbox.

Comment: The AppExchange is just a server that holds application metadata. You can't extract the contents of the package, per se, you have to "install" it.

Comment: One thing that we did was to point our Eclipse project to an SVN, and then we could backup versions of our organization just by refreshing and committing, and then we could roll back and so on at will.

Comment: so @sfdcfox if i do the managed package as you said, can i access the components individually? Also, how would I create a managed package to grab everything?

Comment: As far as just a backup solution, go with the unmanaged package instead. You'll have a lot more flexibility at the loss of upgradability, which shouldn't be much of an issue, since you're not trying to list your metadata on the public AppExchange. Once packaged and uploaded, getting the configuration back out requires an install; once installed, the individual pieces can be accessed directly. For creating a package of "everything", that's a manual process of just going through each category and adding all the components of that category.

Answer (score 0):

All the items that you see in the Force.com IDE can be backed up, they will reside in a folder on your disk and can be archived to a separate file system or you can load to an online storage. If you need this online as a repository for source control then there are plenty available such as github, bitbucket.

If you need to do frequent backups then the ANT migration tool is an option: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Migration_Tool_Guide

**Note** Not all items in salesforce can be backed up in this way, here is the list of items that are excluded from the metadata API (used by IDE, ANT and any other tools): http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_unsupported_types.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use CloudAlly ([www.cloudally.com](http://www.cloudally.com)) for that, it is a paid service but automates your backup including Metadata.